# Fourier Transform of Manchester (twinned-binary) function

Tags: fourier-transform

Given the following function used in binary telecommunications:

[image]

I'd like to know how I would obtain $P(f)$ the Fourier transform of this function. The function can be written as:

$$
p(t) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            +1 & \quad 0 \leq \frac{Tb}{2} \\
            -1 & \quad \frac{Tb}{2} \lt Tb
        \end{array}
    \right.
$$

I thought of maybe expressing it as some sort of shifted and truncated $sgn(x)$ function but I'm looking for the easiest/simplest mathematical solution.

Comment: The Fourier transform of the Heaviside step function is a bit troublesome; the direct approach yields
$$
\hat H(\omega) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_0^\infty e^{-i\omega t}\ \mathsf dt = \lim_{x\to\infty} \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\cdot \frac{1-e^{-i\omega x}}{i\omega},
$$
but this limit does not exist. Rather, the correct answer is
$$
\hat H(\omega) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{i\omega} + \sqrt{\frac\pi 2}\delta(\omega),
$$
where $\delta(\cdot)$ is the Dirac delta function. See here: https://www.cs.uaf.edu/~bueler/M611heaviside.pdf

Comment: Applying this logic to $p(t) = H(t)-2H(t-T_b/2)+H(t-T_b)$ we have
$$
\hat p(\omega) = \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\frac1{i\omega}\left(-1+2 e^{iT_b\omega/2}-e^{iT_b\omega}\right).
$$